# Create a dynamic host group based on the specific Manufacturer

Tags: json, regex, loops, ansible

I have a test playbook where I have 5 nodes and I need to create a dynamic host group if the Manufacturer of that nodes is XYZ company

So far, I have tried these and able to loop through nodes and get a Manufacturer using

```
- name: Filter the Manufacturer of Nodes
  hosts: Test
  tasks:
  - name: Get facts from hosts
    redfish_info:
      category: Chassis
      command: GetChassisInventory
      baseuri: "{{ hostvars[item]['nodes_list'] }}"
      username: "{{ }}"
      password: "{{ }}"
    register: chassis_facts
    with_items:
    - "{{ groups.webservers }}"
    - "{{ groups.dbservers  }}"
  - debug:
      var: chassis_facts.results
```

What should now happen is I need to create a dynamic host group using `add_host` module

```
- name: Add the hosts dynamically as per Manufacturer
  add_host:
    groups: xyz_hosts
    hostname: "{{ item }}"
  when: chassis_facts.results[*].redfish_facts | json_query(some_regex_filter) 
  with_items:
  - "{{ groups.webservers }}"
  - "{{ groups.dbservers }}"
```

based on the Manufacturer from above node list using `json_query` filter. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, after much digging I found an answer to this, Im using below module which did the trick.

```
 - name: create a new host group based on Manufacturer
    add_host:
      groups: webservers
      hostname: "{{ item }}"
      inventory_dir: "{{inventory_dir}}"
    when: '"xyz Company" in 
    result.results[0].redfish_facts.chassis.entries[0].Manufacturer'
    with_items:
      - "{{ groups.webservers }}"
```